# Selenium hangs for modals in firefox browser for very long time

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium2, java, selenium-webdriver

[image]

After opening the modal window or modal overlay , performing any click operation within the modal takes very long time. It doesn't throw any exception neither does the execution stops.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("selectRecord")).click();// It opens a pop-up containing records .
log("Pop-up opened");
driver.findElement(By.id("record_1")).click();
Reporter.log("record clicked");
```

After the pop-up opens webdriver get's hanged for very long time and the next click operation is not performed (ie clicking on element with id record_1) neither does it comes to next line.

I'm using the following environment :

FF : 34.0

Selenium : 2.44

Suggest some workarounds if there's an issue with Selenium itself.

Comment: what code have you written? Did you try using 2.45 and see if this issue still persists?

Comment: @log_file : simple code to perform web driver click operation. FYI the modal is not a browser pop-up it's just a simple modal pop-up within the parent window . The issue persists for 2.45 , 2.46.and 2.47 as well .

Comment: Code? URL? Same issue with Chrome?

Comment: @FDM : I have attached a screenshot of the pop-up window and a rough code snippet. Hope it helps to clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, carefully downgrade your Firefox to version 31 or 31.0.6  and it should work.  Firefox support is sketchy after version 32 or later since native events aren't handled any more.  So, if you use firefox 32 or later, you need to be very careful to avoid native events (such as driver.get or driver.navigate.to) and try to use Javascript wherever possible (or already implied, such as in driver.findElement).